# This job appears to have stopped responding - CircleCI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, circleci

I run deployment of a ReactJs project on CircleCI, the job is failed when it comes to step building project. The step takes more than 10 mins with no output.

I tried to add flag `no_output_timeout: 20m` and `echo 'timeout = 1200' >> ~/.bashrc`, but no luck. It's still failing after 10 min. Any suggestion is appreciated!

```
#16 [10/12] RUN yarn build --verbose
#16 0.573 yarn run v1.17.3
#16 0.597 $ GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false craco build --verbose
#16 0.780 craco:  Project root path resolved to:  /app
#16 0.781 craco:  Config file path resolved to:  /app/craco.config.js
#16 0.810 craco:  Override started with arguments:  [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
#16 0.810   '/app/node_modules/@craco/craco/scripts/build.js',
#16 0.810   '--verbose' ]
#16 0.810 craco:  For environment:  production
#16 0.810 craco:  Found craco config file at:  /app/craco.config.js
#16 0.813 craco:  Overrided craco config with plugin.
#16 0.814 craco:  Applied craco config plugins.
#16 0.820 craco:  Found Webpack prod config at:  /app/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
#16 2.550 craco:  Overrided ESLint config to enable an ignore file.
#16 2.551 craco:  Overrided PostCSS loader.
#16 2.551 craco:  Overrided PostCSS loader.
#16 2.551 craco:  Overrided PostCSS loader.
#16 2.551 craco:  Overrided PostCSS loader.
#16 2.557 craco:  Applied webpack config plugins.
#16 2.557 craco:  Overrided require cache for module: /app/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
#16 2.557 craco:  Overrided Webpack prod config.
#16 2.557 craco:  Building CRA at:  /app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js
#16 2.713 Creating an optimized production build...
#16 3.765 Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
#16 3.765 npx browserslist@latest --update-db
#16 3.765 
#16 3.765 Why you should do it regularly:
#16 3.765 https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
ERRO[0542] got 3 SIGTERM/SIGINTs, forcing shutdown
```

Comment: I'm likely stating the obvious, but if you tried with the CircleCI attribute `no_output_timeout: 20m` and it's still occurring after 10 minutes, then the timeout comes from somewhere else ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Or is it now failing after 10 minutes for another reason than a timeout?

Comment: Thanks! It turned out the Circle CI machine is too small for building process. Need to increase resource class.